# Top menu disappears when exiting NavigationLink

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

This system works as follows, when the application starts, the news feed is launched, there is also a side menu button on the top left. When I open the menu and go to any page and exit back with a swipe (not the built-in back button), then after exiting to the main page, the menu disappears and in general everything that is at the top

```
`import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AuthViewModel
    
    
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
//                        if let _ = viewModel.user {
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                //                if viewModel.isEmailVerified == true {
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack{
                        if isShowing {
                            SideMenuView(isShowing: $isShowing)
                        }
                        TabView {
                            News()
                                .tabItem{
                                    Image(systemName: "house")
                                }
                            
                            Search()
                                .tabItem{
                                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                }
                            
                            Messages()
                                .tabItem{
                                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                                }
                        }
                        .accentColor(.purple)
                        .navigationBarTitle("App")
                        .cornerRadius(isShowing ? 20 : 10)
                        .offset(x: isShowing ? 400 : 0, y: 0)
                        .scaleEffect(isShowing ? 0.8 : 1)
                        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                            withAnimation(.spring()){
                                isShowing.toggle()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            if let user = viewModel.user {
                                KFImage(URL(string: user.profileImageUrl))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .clipped()
                                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                                    .cornerRadius(16)
                            }
                        }))
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                    }
                    .onAppear{
                        isShowing = false
                    }
                }
            }  /*else {
                LoginView()
                } */
            /*/}*/else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}`




`import SwiftUI

struct SideMenuView: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if let user = viewModel.user {
            ZStack {
                Color.clear
                VStack {
                    SideMenuHeaderView(isShowing: $isShowing)
                        .frame(height: 240)
                    
                    ForEach(SideMenuViewModel.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                        if option == .profile{
                            NavigationLink {
                                UserProfileView(user: user)
                            } label: {
                                SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            }
                            
                        } else if option == .bookmarks {
                            NavigationLink {
                                SavedWishesView(user: user)
                            } label: {
                                SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            }
                            
                        } else if option == .blackList {
                            NavigationLink {
                                BlackList(user: user)
                            } label: {
                                SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            }
                        } else if option == .settings {
                            NavigationLink {
                                SettingView()
                            } label: {
                                SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Spacer()
                        } else if option == .logout {
                            Button {
                                viewModel.signOut()
                            } label: {
                                SideMenuOptionView(viewModel: option)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                            .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

The well-known assistant did not help me in any way, so I did not find any other way out but to embarrass myself here

Comment: You have quite a few issues, to start…TabView should always be at the top per HIG, each tab has to have their own NavigationStack/View